# How to receive json from axios post method

Tags: json, laravel, axios, form-data

Im sending post using axios with:

```
const request = await axios.post('/api/person', {name, age});
```

In laravel store function using:

```
$data = json_decode($request->getContent(), true);
```

and when i use `var_dump($data['name']);` it displays value but when im trying to validate it with `if(isset($data['name']))` returns false
Whats a good way to use json as data source instead of Form Data?

Comment: are you sure it's $data['name'] and not $data['data']['name'] . In my experiences a JSON return generally gives you a data object.

Comment: what is the value? If `$data['name']` is null, then `isset` will return false.